# Yellow exclamation mark top-right corner component. What does it mean?

Tags: java, swing, components

There is this annoying symbol that appears on the top right corner of a component while i was using swing and i have no idea what it means. Once it appears it becomes impossible to align the component properly which makes it infuriating.

Top-right. Yellow symbol with the exclamation in the middle:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TrK8.png]

This time (not the first time this happen) it appeared after i moved a panel to the wrong place (it was a just a order reshuffling but ended up with a new tab somehow) and after moving it back (Dragging it back using the navigator) it showed this symbol.

It isnt clickable, there is no tooltip. It is just standing there and somehow messing up with the component alignment. It probably causes more than that but i am not sure.

I got rid of it by pressing CTRL+Z but i wanna know what that means, why that even appears and how to get rid of it properly. This appeared multiple times these days and IIRC i had to delete a whole component because of it.

Comment: This comes from your IDE's GUI designer. Might pay to identify both the IDE & GUI design plug-in. OTOH it'd probably pay better to set all that nonsense aside until you learn how to create a GUI using pure Java code. Then it becomes a lot easier to work with & understand the designers that can make it so much faster. At the moment it seems that using the designer is slowing things down & making them more frustrating & complicated.

Comment: Baby steps. While i am starting to notice there is just so much swing can do for me i am not ready to abandon it completely.

Comment: The IDE is trying to tell that there is a collision in your components (overlap)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I think it is something like this. As far as i can tell swing have a problem identifying the component is inside another component and not overlapping.

Comment: *"Baby steps."* No, this is more: baby teetering on the edge of the stairs before tumbling chaotically down them. While learning how to use the toolkit has an overhead, the investment will pay off quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am making a wild guess here. But it looks to me as if using the design view messed up your Java code. Did you check for methods that set layouts and Bounds(setLayout, setBounds) in your code? Your panel might be overlapping other components or wrongly set. There are various anomalies here. Can you upload the code?

or just check for

```
setBounds(int,int); //It places components according to given coordinates
setLayout()  // It might be a wrong layout?
```

Comment: I didnt notice any change in the code but since i am a newbie and the swing generated code isnt the more organized possible i might have missed it. A quick CTRL+F search turned as no matches for "bounds". I tried changing layouts but nothing changed. I uploaded an new image showing the weidest part of this problem. Code coming tomorrow since it is 4Am here...